# How to submit form data to the SQL database correctly?

Tags: php, html, sql, database

This is the form I have where I submit my data

```html
<p align="center" style="color:#F00;">
  <?php echo $msg; ?>
</p>
<form class="form-horizontal style-form" name="form1" method="post" action="Create-jobs.php" onSubmit="return validate();">
  <p style="color:#F00"></p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" style="padding-left:40px;">Job Title</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="job_title" placeholder="&lt;Enter Job name&gt;">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" style="padding-left:40px;">Job Description</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <textarea class="form-control" name="job_des" placeholder="&lt;Enter a detailed description&gt;" cols="17" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" style="padding-left:40px;">Job Requirements</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="job_reqs" placeholder="&lt;Enter requirements seperated by a comma&gt;">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label" style="padding-left:40px;">Is the job active?(y/n)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="job_reqs" placeholder="y/n">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="margin-left:15px; margin-bottom:15px;">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Job" class="btn btn-theme"></div>
</form>
```

And this is the php code I use to submit the form data.

```
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS' ,'');
define('DB_NAME', 'loginsystem');
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
    $jobtitle = $_POST['job_title'];
    $jobdes = $_POST['job_des'];
    $jobreqs = $_POST['job_reqs'];
    $jobactive = "";

    if(job_active == "y") {
        $jobactive = '1';
    } else {
        if(job_active == "n") {
            $jobactive = '0';
        } else {
            $msg = "error in job_active.";
        }
    }   

    $sql = "INSERT INTO jobs (jobID, job_title, job_des, job_reqs, job_active, Posting_date) VALUES (NULL, '$jobtitle', '$jobdes', '$jobreqs', '$jobactive', current_timestamp()')";

    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $msg = "it worked successfully!";
} else {
    $msg = "error submitting form.";
}
```

I enter the data correctly and the code executes passing all my checks.($msg = "it worked successfully is being triggered.) but the database itself doesn't update. I checked to see if the database itself is faulty but my other pages that read database data function normally. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You're not checking the result of `mysqli_query()`, why do you think it worked successfully?

Comment: You should learn to use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: You have an extra `'` after `current_timestamp()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end of the SQL statement you left a single quotation mark. Try to fix it first and if it will not help, then print the SQL and try to insert it manually to MySQL, it should show what is wrong.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO jobs (jobID, job_title, job_des, job_reqs, job_active, Posting_date) VALUES (NULL, '$jobtitle', '$jobdes', '$jobreqs', '$jobactive', current_timestamp())";
```